# Sublime Text 3: All Dropdown Options lead to blank tabs

Tags: python, anaconda, sublimetext3

I have Anaconda installed.
I go to preferences->package settings->anaconda->literally any option at all
I get a blank tab. Literally absolutely nothing.

My computer seems to be aware that what I'm seeing is not the actual contents of the file. If I x out the tab, I get a popup saying that the file has been modified, asking if I want to save changes.

edit: the console shows the following error:
"Unable to open /C/Users/myname/AppData/Roaming/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User/Anaconda.sublime-settings"

The problem seems to be that the file is actually located in "Packages/Anaconda/Anaconda.sublime-settings" not "Packages/User/Anaconda.sublime-settings." Is there a way to set it so Sublime knows to look at the right folder?

Comment: Does the Sublime console display any messages when you pick the file? There is a normal error message that's expected, but anything other than that might provide a clue.

Comment: Aha! it does! Here's what pops up: "Unable to open /C/Users/myname/AppData/Roaming/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User/Anaconda.sublime-settings"